# Антонім до фразеологізму "на заячий скік"

Tags: фразеологізми, антоніми

Для фразеологізму ***комар носа не підточить*** антонім - ***стук-грюк, аби з рук*** [(Мова - ДНК нації)](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/yakisno-i-nedbalo). Чи можна підібрати антоніми (фразеологізми) до інших фразеологізмів?

[Фразеологічний словник української мови](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53399/357825.html)

із (**на**) **за́ячий** (гороб’я́чий, гороби́ний, жа́б’ячий) **скік**. Дуже мало. *На новий рік прибавилось дня на заячий скік* (Укр.. присл..)

Який фразеологізм буде антонімом до фразеологізму ***"на заячий скік"***?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я так розумію, значення цього фразеологізму, що чогось *дуже мало*. То можна антонімами вважати фразеологізми про те, що чогось **дуже багато**. Наприклад:

- М. П. Коломієць, Є. С. Регушевський «Словник фразеологічних синонімів» за ред. В. А. Вінника (Київ, «Радянська школа», 1988, ISBN 5-330-00353-9), [стаття «багато»](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=24&t=8) на с. 10–11:

  - без ліку;
  - кури не клюють;
  - свині не їдять;
  - лопатою горни/греби/загрібай;
  - аж кишить;
  - до біса;
  - як маку;
  - як піску морського;
  - ні проїхати ні пройти;
  - на воловій шкурі не списати;
  - хоч греблю гати;
  - по горло;
  - по вуха;
  - по шию;
  - з головою;
  - по зав’язку;
  - ціла купа;
  - як цвіту в городі / по всьому світу).
- [З сайту «Мова — ДНК нації»](//ukr-mova.in.ua/library/frazeologizmu/duzhe-tisno,-nadzvuchajno-lyudno):

  - ніде курці клюнути;
  - ніде голкою/пальцем ткнути;
  - ніде маковому зерну / яблуку впасти;
  - як оселедців у бочці.